# Why do the first and last "t" in "taste" sound different?

Tags: pronunciation, aspiration, allophones

When I listened to the audio pronunciation of "taste" /teɪst/, I noticed that the first and last "t" sound different: the first "t" sounds like [tʰ] while the second one sounds more like [tsʰ]. Words that end with /t/ such as "it" and "act" also has this [tsʰ] sound.

However, words ending with /k/ or /p/ does not have this different sound (e.g. cake and peep).

Why is the ending /t/ pronounced differently when aspirated?

Comment: _Taste_ does not have a final [tˢʰ] sound in any dialect of English that I know of. Of course, any final consonant _can_ be exaggerated for various effects (including in _cake_ and _keep_); but they are not normally so. [tʰeɪstˢ(ʰ)] would almost certainly be /teɪsts/, i.e., _tastes_. You’re generally more likely to hear the fricativised dental in syllable onset, i.e., [tˢʰeɪst].

Comment: /t/ is only aspirated [tʰ] at the start of a syllable; at the end of a syllable it is not aspirated, and it is usually accompanied by a 'co-articulated' glottal stop. In  some dialects, in fact, the glottal stop *replaces* the apical (tongue tip) articulation. Moreover, in many speech situations the apical closure may be incomplete, as the tongue moves to articulate the following sound; the 'stopness' of the phoneme is handled entirely by the glottal closure.

Comment: @Stoney That rarely applies in s-clusters. /st/ in coda is often simplified to /s/, but the t is not replaced by a glottal stop. [s?] (with “?” representing the glottal stop—typing on my phone) would be exceedingly hard to pronounce, at least without a following vowel, and [tei?s] the obvious way to make it pronounceable, is never heard as far as I know.

Comment: Why would they sound the same?  There's almost no correlation between spelling and sounds, in English.

Comment: The final /t/ closure is often not complete, and the /s/ leaks through. Clusters with fricatives get reversed often enough if this becomes a habit, like _ask/ax_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In my idiolect ʔ is co-articulated when /-st/ is utterance-terminal (*How does it taste?*); the /t/ element vanishes altogether when /s/ may combine with the morphological head of the following syllable as an acceptable onset (*What's it taste like?* - /sl/); and ʔ replaces [t] when neither /s/ nor /t/ combines (*It doesn't taste good.* - /sʔg/). In more carefully articulated contexts the /t/ emerges if it will marry to the following syllable; but that's probably an effect of actor training.

Comment: @Stoney I admit I have never heard that in anyone before. An actual glottal release between [s] and [g] is practically impossible for me to produce without an epenthetic vowel. In ‘taste good’, I have simply /sg/, which of course involves a glottal _closure_, but no release until after the velar release.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Ah, release is something I didn't consider. Glottal *closure* clearly precedes my velar closure, which is all I was thinking about; but glottal *release* is later than velar closure. I can't sequence the releases without an artificial slowdown that precludes my having any confidence in the report.

Comment: @Stoney Ah, that makes more sense. Remember that a glottal closure is usually inaudible in unvoiced surroundings like /st/. Utterance-finally, you’re quite likely to have a glottal closure even without an underlying /t/, so if your /t/ is simply assimilated into the /s/ (common enough), my guess would be that you pronounce utterance-final ‘mace’ and ‘taste’ the same, apart from the initial consonant, or possibly just with a slightly longer [s] in ‘taste’ (that’s what I do, I think).

Comment: In Scouse (i.e. Liverpudlian) stops, especially final ones, are stereotypically affricated. I think that is marginally less likely to happen when /s/ precedes, but it can still occur.

Comment: While I know that ending /t/ is not aspirated, I'm curious about why pronouncing the words "at" and "act" like they do in an online dictionary will produce a sound that feels like [ts] at the end (try this one: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/at_1?q=at#)

Comment: Hin, you might have a great ear for (literally) minimal pairs with phonemes in English that are often ignored by native speakers.  The fine differences in voc onset time and syllable stress cannot, however, be accurately reproduced by a machine. Be wary of the computer-generated pronunciation.  The interdental onset may be less of the perceived affricate when English does not have a near pair with a difference in meaning, but I also suspect you are hearing a stop.

Comment: Isn't the answer... Inflection?

Comment: There is no strict relationship - whatsoever - at all - in any way - not even suggested - between spelling and pronunciation in English. It's Just That Simple.

Comment: Well, there is, a bit.  For example, "m" is never pronounced as anything but /m/.  And if I made up a random nonsense word like "floobockle," I think you could make a fair guess as to how to pronounce it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are five sounds that we classify as /t/ in English: the t's in "top," "stop," "pot," "potter," and "button."  They aren't identical, but we do think of them all as /t/.  You can test some of the difference by putting your hand in front of your mouth as you say them; the amount of breath coming out is different.  These different sounds all classified the same are called "allophones."  Google "english allophones" and you can find more on this.

One useful resource is academia.edu's [English Allophonic Booklet](http://www.academia.edu/3441996/ENGLISH_ALLOPHONIC_BOOKLET).  Note that /p/ and /k/ do actually have allophones as well.  Some of them may be hard to distinguish, but I can hear the difference in the p's in "pal" and "lap."

Why don't all phonemes have the same number of allophones?  For one thing, the sounds occur in different parts of the mouth or in different ways.  But also:  language is arbitrary.  Add "s" to an English word and it will be pronounced /s/ ("cats") or /z/ ("dogs").  Add it to a Spanish word and it's /s/ either way.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I would add that different languages have different phonemes as well as allophones -- for example, in English, [p] and [pʰ] are allophones of the same phoneme, but in Korean, /p/ and /pʰ/ are distinct phonemes, so [pul] and [pʰul] are different words entirely.